# How to expand group for window function in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe with the following columns `id`, `place`, `date`, `value`. There is also list of dates `dates`. The dates are the last days of months. Let us say `value` can take values of `core` and `not core`. I want to create new column `status` the following way : if for the same `id` and `place` in the previous month `status` was `core` and now it is not `core` then `status` is `0` else `1`.

The problem is that for some groups some dates may be missed. For example there is df

```
id     place     value     date
1      A         core      2023-08-31
1      A         not core  2023-09-30
1      A         core      2023-11-30
2      A         core      2023-10-30
2      A         core      2023-11-30
2      B         not core  2023-07-31    
2      B         core      2023-10-31
```

and there is list of dates

```
['2023-07-31', '2023-08-31', '2023-09-30', '2023-10-31', '2023-11-30']
```

I expect to get the following output

```
id     place     value     date          prev_month_value     status
1      A         NONE      2023-07-31    NONE                 1
1      A         core      2023-08-31    NONE                 1
1      A         not core  2023-09-30    core                 0
1      A         NONE      2023-10-31    not core             1
1      A         core      2023-11-30    NONE                 1
2      A         NONE      2023-07-31    NONE                 1
2      A         NONE      2023-08-31    NONE                 1
2      A         NONE      2023-09-30    NONE                 1
2      A         core      2023-10-31    NONE                 1
2      A         core      2023-11-30    core                 1
2      B         not core  2023-07-31    NONE                 1
2      B         NONE      2023-08-31    not core             1
2      B         NONE      2023-09-30    NONE                 1
2      B         core      2023-10-31    NONE                 1
2      B         NONE      2023-11-30    core                 0
```

So far I come up with the following solution:

```
dates_df = pd.DataFrame([dates], names=['date'])

datas = []
for name, group in df.groupby(['id', 'place']):
    local_df = dates_df.assign(id=group['id'].iloc[0], place=group['place'].iloc[0])
    data = group.merge(local_df, on=['id', 'place', 'date'], how='right').sort_values('date')
    data['prev_month_value'] = data['value'].shift(1)
    data['status'] = data.apply(
                     lambda x: 0 if x['prev_month_value'] == 'core' and x['value'] != 'core' else 0,
                     axis=1
    )
    datas.append(data)
result_df = pd.concat(datas)
```

I realise that it could be done via `distinct`, but it seems to be very inefficient.

So my questions are:

1. Can it be done faster/more efficient in terms of speed and memory?
2. How can it be done in pyspark? It does not support group iterating and doing distinct filter with subsequent outer join seems to be very slow. However as of now I do not see the other way.

Comment: Can you tell what you want to do with the date data ? It is unclear what is the problem statement

Comment: @Doof, I simplified it for clarity, in my task there is more than one `status` and more sophisticated rule of it computation, but it depends on how `value` changes over `time`, so I need for each `id`, `place` and  `date` know  what the `status` is. The problem itself is to know count of each `status` for each `date`

Answer (score 0):

In Pyspark you can do it using the lead function that gives you the previous value on each group :

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lead,col, when

windowsAgg  = Window.partitionBy("id","place").orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn('status', when(lead('value').over(windowsAgg) == col('value'),1).otherwise(0))
```

Comment: It doesn't solve a problem of missing dates. In your example value will be compared to previous existing row, which can be several months ago, not the previous month.